# Why doesn't the modification of memory at *int_one alter the valueof memory at *int_two?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I wrote a pretty simple piece of C code:

```
int main(void) {
    void *area = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    unsigned int *int_one = (unsigned int *) area;
    unsigned int *int_two = ((unsigned int *) area) + 3;

    *int_two = 4293422034;
    *int_one = 2;

    printf("%u\n%u\n", *int_two, *int_one);

    return 0;
}
```

`sizeof(int)` is `4` on my machine. Per my understanding, shouldn't the modification of memory at address `int_one` have an effect on the value stored at address `int_two`?

Modifying `*int_one` alters the first `4` bytes of mem. address `area` (perhaps not all 4, but enough to warrant the result I'm expecting?), and the integer at address `int_two` starts at the last byte of integer `int_one`.

So, shouldn't changing memory at `int_one` have an effect on memory at `int_two`?
Yet the `printf` call produces `4293422034` and `2` respectively.

I made sure to use unsigned variables to avoid confusion around 2s complement and negative values, and to use a small value for `*int_one` to warrant the change of its last byte (don't know if this is right?)

What am I not getting?

Comment: You should print the two pointers: `printf("%p %p\n", int_one, int_two)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator '+', when applied to a pointer, increases the pointer `n` times the size of the object it points to. So increasing an `int*` by `3` does not add 3 bytes but `3*sizeof(int)` bytes.

Comment: for possible future readers: cast the ptr to a `char` as its size is guaranteed to be `1` byte: `((unsigned char *) area) + 3`

Answer (score 2):

Pointer arithmetic is scaled by the size of the type the pointer points at. (`sizeof(unsigned int)` in your case). You'd need to cast to `(char*)` before adding 3 if you want to increase the address by 3 bytes, but converting that to an `unsigned*` pointer would incur *undefined behavior* by violating alignment requirements ([6.3.2.3p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7))) and dereferencing the pointer would make the program even "more undefined" by violating strict aliasing rules ([6.5p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7)).

To realy do this kind of type punning right, you'd need to use `memcpy` (or `union`s).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    void *area = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    if(!area) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    unsigned int *int_one_p = area;
    void *int_two_p = (((char*) area) + 3); /*saving this to an (unsigned*) would be UB*/

    memcpy(int_two_p,&(unsigned){4293422034},sizeof(unsigned));
    memcpy(int_one_p,&(unsigned){2},sizeof(unsigned));

    unsigned one,two;
    memcpy(&one,int_one_p, sizeof(one));
    memcpy(&two,int_two_p, sizeof(two));

    printf("%u\n%u\n", two, one);

    return 0;
}
```